# How to style overall form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

**Problem**

I have a lot of pages with standalone forms. Because of webdesign issues I ended up using the form element to style.

The problem is certain actions cause the form-id to change.

```
<form id="user-profile-form">

 //a failed file upload causes the above to become

<form id="user-profile-form--2">
```

Which breaks a lot of my css.

An example form HTML profile:

```
<form id="user-profile-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/drupalie/user/184/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        /*form is built in here*/
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to add a CSS class to my form, add a class to the empty div which surrounds all the form elements or as a last resort, prevent the form increment on certain forms.

Comment: I posted an answer, but next time please at least read the docs, OK? [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7s) is a must-have, no one can remember everything so I strongly suggest bookmarking it and keeping it open during form development.

Comment: Aah shoot, sorry I should've checked that. I just assumed it was only used for elements. Thank you for answering anyway!

Comment: It's somehow misleading format of Form API docs... there is "pseudo-element" form listed in it, that represents overall form. But I agree it's easy to miss it - it looks like real elements in the table.

Comment: Feature request to documentation team [here](https://drupal.org/node/2120411#comment-8000475)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add classes you need directly to your form with [`#attributes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes). This is example directly from the official documentation:

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('search-form'));
```

If it's not your code that creates form, you can add this with [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Just be careful not to overwrite any attributes or classes that might be already in place:

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-form';
```